# How to connect oracle DB using JDBC URL or connection String in Perl script

Tags: oracle, perl, ojdbc, perlscript

I have a jdbc connection string and want to connect db in perl script, but no idea how to do it.

```
my $connstr = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://server:port/db_name,cn=OracleContext,dc=world';
my $user = "***";
my $pass = "###";

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:$connstr", $user, $pass)
```

Getting below error::

```
 DBI connect('jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://server:port/db_name,cn=OracleContext,dc=world',...) failed: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002)
```

Comment: `@ldap` will be interpolated as an array, and turned into the empty string. Unless you by chance have such an array defined. You should always use `use strict; use warnings` to catch such errors when they occur. If you change the double quotes to single quotes to prevent interpolation, it might work.

Comment: Thanks, Now i am getting proper string as used single quotes but still same issue

Comment: perl DBI uses standard native oracle connection string which one would also use with tools like sqlplus. for starters that excludes java specific things before @ character.

Comment: Isn't the DBI module equipped with its own error reporting? Like you would do `DBI->connect(...) or die DBI->Errstr()`? Check documentation for syntax.

Comment: @prabjotsingh Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes, I was on windows

Answer (score 3):

In perl you don't put the OID in the connection string, perl uses standard `sqlnet.ora`, `ldap.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` file. Simply try

```
DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:db_name", $user, $pass);
```

Ensure that your `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable is properly set.